# How to define a hybrid expression?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, hybrid

I have two classes, Event and Booking. One Event can hold many bookings.

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    space = Column(Integer)

class Booking(Base):
    __tablename_ = 'booking'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('event.id'))
    event = relationship('Event', backref=backref('bookings'))
```

Now I want to calculate the occupancy and decided to go for a hybrid property of the Event class, like this:

```
@hybrid_property
def occupancy(self):
    return float(len(self.bookings)) / float(self.space)
```

This works fine in some cases, but when I want to be able to filter on occupancy, like this:

```
session.query(Event).filter(Event.occupany > 0.5)
```

Doing that I get this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' has no len()
```

So I realized I probably need a hybrid expression and came up with:

```
@occupancy.expression
def occupancy(cls):
    return func.count(select([Booking.id]).where(cls.id == Booking.event_id).label('occupancy')) / cls.space
```

This however results in a MySQL error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) 
(1111, 'Invalid use of group function') [SQL: u'SELECT event.id AS 
event_id FROM event \nWHERE count((SELECT booking.id \nFROM booking 
\nWHERE event.id = booking.event_id)) / event.space > %s'] 
[parameters: (0.5,)]
```

How can I construct the hybrid expression? Or is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Count in the subquery, not in the enclosing query: `select([func.count(Booking.id)]).where(...)...`.

Comment: Yes! Your comment is the actual answer. Thank you. If you write it as a real answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counting should be done inside the [scalar subquery](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.label). The current query is trying to apply the `count()` function to the result set of the subquery in the WHERE clause of the enclosing query, which on the other hand has no grouping, and so you get the error – not to mention that aggregate functions as predicates belong in a HAVING clause. Just move the call:

```
@occupancy.expression
def occupancy(cls):
    stmt = select([func.count(Booking.id)]).\
        where(cls.id == Booking.event_id).\
        label('occupancy')
    return stmt / cls.space
```